# React Router 4 routes property

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a setup in react-router 3 that worked nicely for nested components. Now when I try to do the same in react-router V4 I can't seem to get it to work. 
I've read a few articles including the docs and still can't get it to work. I'm posting first my setup in react-router 3. Then after that what I have tried for react-router 4

React Router 3 Setup
**App.js**

```
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Store from './store';
import routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={Store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes}/>
  </Provider>
  ,document.querySelector('#react-container'));
```

**routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import MainLayout from './layouts/main';
import NotFound from './pages/notfound';
import Home from './pages/home';




export default (
        <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </Route>
);
```

**layouts/main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/header';
import Footer from '../components/footer';

export default class MainLayout extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
              <div id="page-content">{this.props.children}</div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

---

**React-router 4** I'm trying to figure out how to use my layout.js nesting like I did in React Router 3

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Store from './store';
import routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={Store}>
    <Router routes={routes}/>
  </Provider>
  ,document.querySelector('#react-container'));
```

**routes.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

    import MainLayout from './layouts/main';
    import NotFound from './pages/notfound';
    import Home from './pages/home';


   export default (
        // <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
        //  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        //  <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        // </Route>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={MainLayout}/>
          <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If MainLayout is going to be the container (layout) for all of your sections (Home, etc), then you can put your child routes for MainLayout inside of MainLayout:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/header';
import Footer from '../components/footer';

const Main = ({match}) => {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div id="page-content">
              <Route path={match.url + '/home'} component={Home} />
              <Route path={match.url + '/about'} component={About} />
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main
```

If you have more than a few sections using MainLayout you can create an array of all the routes and their related components and `map` through them.